# How to rename value in column, extracting part of it?

Tags: python, python-3.x, dataframe, rename

if my dataframne looks like this:

```
id      value
s1    like_val
q2    upd_val
b3    opt_far_val
a3    string_upload
```

How to keep only values in second column that have _val at the end to get:

```
id      value
s1      val
q2      val
b3      val
a3    string_upload
```

How to do that? should I use str.replace?

Comment: `df.value.str.replace('.*_val',"val")`

Answer (score 0):

You could use `str.endswith`:

```
>>> df.where(~df["value"].str.endswith("_val"), "val")

    id          value
0  val            val
1  val            val
2  val            val
3   a3  string_upload
```